# Can't resolve a local npm module made by npm pack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

I created a local module using `npm pack`, which created a package: "org-header-0.0.3.tgz"

In a React project, I added `org-header` to its `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "org-header": "file:[path-to-org-header]/org-header-0.0.3.tgz",
 ...
}
```

It installs fine. However, when I try to use it:

```
import Header from 'org-header';

...
```

However when I do `npm run start`:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Layout.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'org-header' in '/Users/imyjimmy/***/src/components'
```

Could it be because:

1. I did not structure the org-header project correctly
2. Webpack is doing something weird
3. Both?

Answer (score 3):

I also encounter the same issue the other day. Just post my solution here if it helps.

So I'm testing a local dependency (project B) update in my main project (project A) through

1. `npm pack` --> generate the `tgz` file
2. refer the `tgz` file in the project A's `package.json` as above question shows
3. run `npm install` in project A to unpack the package -- installation works fine
4. run into below error when `npm develop`

```
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
Can't resolve 'project B' in '/Users/xxx@xxx.com/projectA/src/pages'
```

What this error indicates is that the package Project A does not exist.
This is weird because when I ran `npm list project B`  I actually got the confirmation that it exists.

**The solution is to explicitly install project B again e.g.`npm install project B` , instead of running `npm install` after you change the `package.json` in step 3.**

I don't know if it's webpack got confused by the 2 packages or somewhat, but the solution solved my problem .